# How do I inverse my selection in "find and replace"?

Tags: notepad++, regex

```
%%& BUNCH OF TEXT &%%ASDA WR
ASDAR
ASDSETSF
ASDSADGSRT
%%& EVEN MORE TEXT &%%
aSDAER
ASD
%%&TEXT HERE TOO &%%
```

I'm trying to remove all of the junk text between the "&%%" and "%%&" segments using expressions in the find and replace tool and am a little lost.

One expression I tried was(?=%).*(?=%) which selects exactly opposite of what I need to delete.

Any pointers would be welcomed with an open mind and a warm embrace!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit

```
"ASDA WR
ASDAR
ASDSETSF
ASDSADGSRT
%%& EVEN MORE TEXT &%%
aSDAER
ASD"
```

Using the expression

```
(\&%%)+([^%\&]*)(%%\&)+     <---I HAD THIS WRONG This didn't work
(\&%%)+.*(%%\&)             <---This is what I had put. This resulted in everything being deleted.
```

will result in everything above to be deleted.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT Fresh Sample

```
LU ASD#$$
%%&USER=ASD#$$ NAME=JOHN DOE     UP      OWNER=ASDWE     CREATED=03.232+&%%
DEFAULT-GROUP=ASD#$$    PASSDATE=00.000 PASS-INTERVAL= 30 PHRASEDATE=N\A
ATTRIBUTES=NONE
REVOKE DATE=NONE RESUME DATE = NONE
%%&LAST-ACCESS=23.346/24:43:23&%%
    LU ASD#$$
%%&USER=ASD#$$ NAME=JOHN DOE     UP      OWNER=ASDWE     CREATED=03.232+&%%
DEFAULT-GROUP=ASD#$$    PASSDATE=00.000 PASS-INTERVAL= 30 PHRASEDATE=N\A
ATTRIBUTES=NONE
REVOKE DATE=NONE RESUME DATE = NONE
%%&LAST-ACCESS=23.346/24:43:23&%%
LU ASD#$$
%%&USER=ASD#$$ NAME=JOHN DOE     UP      OWNER=ASDWE     CREATED=03.232+&%%
DEFAULT-GROUP=ASD#$$    PASSDATE=00.000 PASS-INTERVAL= 30 PHRASEDATE=N\A
ATTRIBUTES=NONE
REVOKE DATE=NONE RESUME DATE = NONE
%%&LAST-ACCESS=23.346/24:43:23&%%
```

Nope still not having any luck.

Comment: No my answer does not delete anything from edit because there is no %%& for closing &%% and vice versa

Comment: Are you sure it deletes whole thing? Can you try just Find and see if this selects all the text?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `I HAD THIS WRONG This didn't work`.

Comment: The expression I accidentally used deletes the whole thing, the one you gave me doesn't seem to want to run.

Comment: I hope you don't have any leading/trailing spaces when you copied my expression because it works pretty fine for me with text in original question

Comment: @tumchaaditya There are not any trailing **spaces** when I copied it. I just finished manually typing and got the same result.

Comment: Well then I give up because it works perfectly fine for me. Does it work for the sample text you have mentioned in **original** question?

Comment: Confirmed it **does** work with the text in the question, why it refuses to work on the text I need it to work on doesn't make any sense.

I will have to keep my search going.

Comment: Can you paste your main text on pastebin unless it has some confidential stuff..

Comment: Check above in a minute or so and I will create a better sample. (Just with modified data).

Comment: @tumchaaditya Done

Comment: Judging from youre fresh sample, I think you are confusing stuff. You want to replace stuff between `&%%` and `%%&` **OR** between `%%&` and `&%%`? They are different! **@mods:** OP does not have enough rep to start a chat to keep comment thread shorter.

Comment: @tumchaaditya basically everything between %%& and &%% needs to be saved. 

I am trying to move all of the data between those segments.

Comment: So I take that you want to **replace** all `last-access` lines, right?

Comment: Opposite, everything that is not **"last-access"** **"User"** **"Name"** **"Owner"** **"Created"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
(\&[\r\n]*%[\r\n]*%)+([^%\&]*)(%[\r\n]*%[\r\n]*\&)+
```

The cleaned file should be

```
%%& BUNCH OF TEXT  EVEN MORE TEXT 
TEXT HERE TOO &%%
```

If you don't want to lose `&%%` and `%%&`, that can also be done.
Replace with `(\&[\r\n]*%[\r\n]*%)+([^%\&]*)(%[\r\n]*%[\r\n]*\&)+` with `(\&%%)\n(%%\&)`

And you need to enable `. matches newline` option

Comment: Nope that one didn't work. I sincerely appreciate the help though!

Comment: OK that . matches newline option makes a big difference; however, see above for the edit.

Comment: I cane see any edit..

Comment: Should be posted now (I was worried about format)

Comment: Updated the answer which I believe should work(Except for junk text at beginning and end of file which you can manually delete)

Comment: Works perfect for what I need to do, thank you sincerely for helping me out!